# Which property of radicals is applied here?

Tags: radicals

A really quick and simple question.

why is

[image] = [image]

which radical properties have been applied?

Comment: note that radical is power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt[4]{x}}{x}=\frac{x^{\frac{1}{4}}}{x^1}=x^{\frac{1}{4}-1}=x^{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{4}{4}}=x^{\frac{1-4}{4}}=x^{-\frac{3}{4}}=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{4}}}$$

Comment: @Daniele You're welcome, I'm glad that I could help.